# tmux issue-- duplicate characters in command line

Tags: linux, tmux

i download the oh-my-tmux theme from https://github.com/gpakosz/.tmux.git and install it in mac M1. when i am trying to type command, it will like something in the screenshot. When i type ls, it will give me two lsls, when i type neofetch, it give me something others. Other command will be also like this, give me duplicate characters. When i do not use this theme, everything goes well. does anyone know what is the problem? i am quite puzzled about this and there is no answer when i am googling it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
cd ~
cp .tmux/.tmux.conf.local .
```

edit ~/.tmux.conf.local add

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```